# how to import data in neo4j via sql connection instead of csv?

Tags: mysql, neo4j, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-neo4j

I am using a NEO4J graph database but my application data is stored in MySQL database. My need is I want to import data in NEO4J via SQL connection instead of Csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need the APOC Procedures library for this one, and you'll also need the MySQL jdbc driver jar in your plugins folder as well.

[APOC Procedures Load JDBC documentation](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_loading_data_from_rdbms)

[APOC Procedures Load JDBC example of usage](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_load_jdbc)